# How to config Nlog to delete log file after a month?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, logging, nlog

The log files after one month time need to be deleted.

Following is configurations in my Nlog.config file:

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs\${date:format=yyyy_MM}\${date:format=dd}.log" 
    layout="..." 
    
    archiveFileName="logs\archive\log.{#}.txt" <!-- actually I don't want to rename or move it -->
    archiveEvery="Month"
    maxArchiveFiles="1"
/>
```

How can I get it work?

Comment: From the [File target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target), it can not delete the specified expired files. But through these two parameters (maxArchiveFiles,archiveEvery), log files exceeding a certain capacity can be deleted regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLog supports two archive-modes, but one [should not be mixing](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#dynamic-vs-static-archive-logic) them:

- **Dynamic FileName Archive Logic** - Enabled by using `fileName="${shortdate}.log"`. This means it will roll / archive dynamically because of the layout-renderer-logic.
- **Static FileName Archive Logic** - Enabled by using `archiveEvery="Month"` and `archiveFileName="..."`. This means it will expect the FileName to be static (Ex. `fileName="app.log"`).

NLog does not currently support archive-cleanup of sub-folders, so instead I suggest doing this:

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs\${date:format=yyyy_MM_dd}.log" maxArchiveDays="31" />
```

Alternative setup a scheduled task to run once a week that executes cleanup of old files, and also removes empty sub-folders.